# image analysis/openCV object detection

Tags: image, image-processing, opencv, image-manipulation, ocr

I'm attempting to experiment and get started with image analysis and OpenCV

My aim is to detect certain objects in random pictures, which are easy to detect, for example: symbols and brand logos. I'd also like to be able to detect more variable features like facial features, porn features. usecase: autotagging, autofiltering

My questions:

1. Where should I start learning applied image-analysis in the context of my aims?
2. What are important existing concepts/approches that I should introduce myself to?
3. What are good existing solutions/components of OpenCV which i can feed with training-datasets of example pictures showing the objects of interest and then make a human manually outline the shapes of interest in order to make it learn to detect the features.

Comment: quite a lot of questions in one go. Anyways, I's say use the [Learning OpenCV](http://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/vision/dipakmj/papers/OReilly%20Learning%20OpenCV.pdf) book for starters, join the yahoo tech-group for OpenCV as well as make Google your friend. :)

Comment: PS - the `haar classifier` provided with OpenCV can be used for training.

Comment: Your question is a little too vague if you ask me. You ought to do some research before posting questions like this.